# can't access localhost from android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm trying to call a java webservice running in my localhost, from a android application running on an emulator on the same machine, here is my code:

```
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/MobileMiddleware/Registration";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 30000);
        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request);
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
            httppost.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Result = EntityUtils
                    .toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d(" return Result>>", Result);

        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {}
        catch (IOException e) {  }
        return null;
    }
```

this code returns error message `Connection timeout, the gateway could not receive a timely response from the website`
help please

Comment: are sure of the port number and is the server up?

Comment: May your personal firewall be blocking either the emulator's 'outbound' or the server's inbound connections?

Comment: I'm not sure you can even do something like this, since the Emulator uses NAT (Network Address Translation) to access networks and internet. Means, he uses the same IP Address as the host computer, so the host itself is unreachable for it. You best chance is to run the service and the emulator on different machines with individual IP addresses.

Comment: try to hit the url on browser and see the result

Comment: @Jürgen: It should work, see http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking .

Comment: @HannoBinder Cool, I didn't know that. So 10.0.2.2 should work as a route to the host system.